# Bring data without postback on click of link

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I was thinking to implement fetching of data with ajax request on click of a link. I know how to work with $.ajax and other xhr request methods. I wanted to know some infromation on the following case. I went to http://www.facebook.com/?sk=welcome
and then I clicked "Find Friends" I noticed the url changed to http://www.facebook.com/?sk=ff and the data in the right hand side was refreshed(without postback) and my friends were loaded. The strange thing I noticed was that no XHR request was logged (I was looking with FireBug console) which I expected to be. How does FB do that with any XHR request? **Does FB uses Iframe for it, if not, then how does it refreshes a section of page with fresh data without postback without some XHR request (in this case)**.

How client can call server's data without postback, without iframe and without some ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook uses invisible iFrames.

Here's the content of one of them:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<span id="fbEmuTrackingSuccess">Success</span>
</body>
</html>
```

The source is a URL full of params. So I guess it's sending all its Ajax requests by changing the iframe URL, performing the callback when the iFrame is loaded, based on the content of the iFrame's body.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how Facebook does it, but it can be done by dynamically loading a script element. For example:

```
function getFriend(id) {
    var newScript = document.createElement("script");
    newScript.src = "http://example.com/get_friend.php?id=" + id;
    document.body.appendChild(newScript);
}
```

And `get_friend.php` returns:

```
document.getElementById("friend_box").innerHTML = "Your friend's details";
```

Comment: How will I get "Your friend's details"; in above example?